# Rendering problems

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I encountered  with very strange problem with IDEA. If I choose any api level less than 20, I get error
"This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of IntelliJ IDEA. Please update IntelliJ IDEA (Details)"

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Stacktrace:

```html
    org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.RenderingException: This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of IntelliJ IDEA. Please update IntelliJ IDEA
 at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.LayoutLibraryLoader.load(LayoutLibraryLoader.java:90)
 at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidTargetData.getLayoutLibrary(AndroidTargetData.java:149)
 at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.create(RenderService.java:167)
 at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:583)
 at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1900(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
 at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$6$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:528)
 at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
 at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
 at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
 at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
 at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$6.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:523)
 at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
 at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
 at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
 at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
 at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
 at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
 at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
 at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is somebody can help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug:

> The issue is that JetBrains hasn't updated IntelliJ 13 as required. It has been fixed in IntelliJ 14 EAP but the fix hasn't been ported back to 13.

[Source](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74873)

The bug fix was included in 13.1.5, so you don't need to use an EAP version.

Comment: Apart from using IntelliJ 14 EAP or waiting for the final release, I don't think so.

Comment: This bug was fixed in 13.1.5, so you just need to update your IDE.