# IntelliJ Idea render main.xml error

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I have just switched to IntelliJ and would like to use this as my Android IDE, but it seems to be having problems rendering my `main.xml` file. Here is the error that I get:

```
Rendering Problems 
This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of IntelliJ IDEA. Please update IntelliJ IDEA (Details)

org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.RenderingException: This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of IntelliJ IDEA. Please update IntelliJ IDEA
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.LayoutLibraryLoader.load(LayoutLibraryLoader.java:90)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidTargetData.getLayoutLibrary(AndroidTargetData.java:149)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.create(RenderService.java:167)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:485)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have tried all of the suggested solutions from this similar thread: [Intellij Idea Render error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872426/intellij-idea-render-error)

1. Uninstalled SDK Build-Tools v20 and installed SDK Build-Tools v18.0.1
2. Lowered the Android SDK in the preview tab to API 18: Android 4.3.1
3. Deleted and remade project based on a lower Android SDK

I still cannot seem to get IntelliJ to render a preview and I'm at a loss of how to troubleshoot next.

Comment: Did you do as the error message suggests and update your version of IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: @CoryKlein I'm on the latest version of IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably the bug, I have mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095365/rendering-problems/26095456#26095456).

It is fixed in IntelliJ EAP 14 ([Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74873))
It was also fixed in the latest 13.1.5 release.